# SOLR 4.2 - solr.LatLonType type vs solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial, spatial-index, solr4

I am currently using SOLR 4.2 to index geospatial data (latitude and longitude data). I have configured my geospatial field as below.

```
 <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>   

  <field name="latlong"     type="location"   indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

I just want to make sure that I am using the correct SOLR class for performing geospatial search since I am not sure which of the 2 class(LatLonType vs  SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) will be supported by future versions of SOLR.

I assume SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType is an upgraded version of latlong, can someone please confirm if I am right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally recommend the `SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType`.  It's better in many ways, but I wouldn't call it an "upgraded version of `LatLonType`" since that wording suggests it is a derivative which totally false.  It's documented here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4  The main reason to use `LatLonType` (perhaps in conjunction with the new field type) is for distance sorting/relevancy which is better implemented by `LatLonType` still (as of Solr 4.3).

I don't see `LatLonType` going away any time soon; Solr takes backwards compatibility pretty seriously.